Unable to import config.py into nested subdirectory
New to python.  I have the following directory structure - however, I am unable to import my config.py file into bottom level files. I have tried sys.path.append in my __init__.py, as well as importing in my __init__.py files. All ears if there's an easy way to do this.  Thanks!


You should have provided more details. Actually, it depends on how you're doing it. For example, if you run it from the src folder, you can simply do import config, and it will know what you're referring to.
If you run it directly from the instrument.py file, you can use from ... import config.
However, be cautious: this can quickly lead to something hard to understand. If I remember correctly, it's better to avoid using imports this way, and it's often preferable to pass information in the other direction if possible.

So I tried this, and I'm getting "attempted relative import with no known parent package"
